# Does this set family have a name?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

A colleague of mine recently asked me if this set family had a name (see definition of *this* below) .  I didn't know the answer, so I thought I would consult the MO oracle.

Let $\mathcal{S}:=\{ S_1, \dots, S_k \}$ be a family of subsets of $[n]$.  Consider the family $\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{S}}$ formed by taking all sets of the form

$
S_1' \cap \dots \cap S_k'
$

where each $S_i'$ is either $S_i$ or the complement of $S_i$.  Note that we are forced to intersect exactly $k$ such sets.

> Do set families arising in this way have a well-established name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how standard this is, but It makes sense to call this family the [atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(order_theory)) of the corresponding lattice of sets obtained from $\mathcal S$. They can be illustrated as the different regions in a Venn diagram.

Comment: Because of complements, I would not say *lattice* of sets, but *(Boolean) algebra* of sets.


Comment: I agree with both, although I would only call the inclusion-minimal sets atoms.

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking the time to answer/comment.  Said information has been passed along.

Answer (score 4):

In my class of probability and measure theory I am calling it the partition generated by the family.